# Show Zero Sales For Item in SQL Query

Tags: sql, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

Being new to SQL I have a problem with my query that I am sure has a trivial solution. I am trying to make a report for item sales in a specific period and I need to display 0 or empty cell if there are no sales. Instead I don't get item displayed at all.
Current query is:

```
SELECT        stock.stock_item_code, stock.physical_quantity, sales.quantity

FROM            stock_branch_level AS stock LEFT OUTER JOIN
                     booked_sales AS sales ON stock.stock_item_code = sales.stock_item_code
WHERE        (stock.replen_type = 1) AND (sales.created_date > @DateFrom)
```

Thanks

Comment: Nice one. Does exactly what I need. Will have a look what else you can put in the Joins.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`LEFT OUTER JOIN` is the right way to get rows even if there are no sales.

The problem is with your where clause on `sales`.

**Note that when there are no sales all sales columns will be null in that row!**

The solution is to move the restriction on sales.created_date to the join clause:

```
SELECT        stock.stock_item_code, stock.physical_quantity, sales.quantity

FROM            stock_branch_level AS stock LEFT OUTER JOIN
                     booked_sales AS sales ON stock.stock_item_code = sales.stock_item_code
                                          AND sales.created_date > @DateFrom
WHERE        (stock.replen_type = 1)
```